# How to copy an array of characters to a char pointer without using strcpy

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings

How would I go about copying the characters of a char array into a char pointer without using strcpy aka manually. For example:

```
char *Strings[NUM];
char temp[LEN];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
    fgets(temp, LEN, stdin);
    Strings[i] = malloc(strlen(temp)+1);    
    Strings[i] = temp; // What would go here instead of this, 
                       // because this causes this to happen->
}
```

```
Input:
Hello
Whats up?
Nothing

Output (when the strings in the array of char pointers are printed):
Nothing
Nothing
Nothing
```

I'm not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: what's wrong with strcpy?

Comment: Use `strdup` for a one-liner...

Comment: `Strings[i] = temp;` overwrites the *pointer* you just had from `malloc`. You cannot copy strings in C like this. And you get memory leak because it is now impossible to `free` that pointer.

Comment: Copying a string "by hand", in a loop, is one of the "classical" CS1 exercises. I suggest you borrow any intro C book and read the chapter about strings.

Comment: Use `strdup()` it's the simplest way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So what is happening is you change the value of temp but all the pointers point to the one instance of temp. You need to allocate the memory and then copy over the array manually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int LEN = 20;
    int NUM = 3;
    char* Strings[NUM];
    char temp[LEN];
    int i,j;

    for (i=0;i<NUM;i++){
        fgets(temp,LEN,stdin);
        Strings[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(temp)+1);    

        for(j=0;j<=strlen(temp);j++) { /* this part */
            if (j == strlen(temp))
                Strings[i][j - 1] = temp[j]; /* overwrite \n with the terminating \0 */
            else
                Strings[i][j] = temp[j];
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<NUM;i++)
        printf("%s\n", Strings[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't copy the `'\0'` terminator - nor detect and ignore the `newline` typically present when using `fgets`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know if there was another way to do it without copying letter by letter, but that works.

Comment: @Robert it should be `for(j=0;j<=strlen(temp);j++)` to copy the terminator too. Otherwise it works "by luck".

Comment: @Robert this *does* copy letter by letter. But `j<strlen(temp) + 1` is not at all idiomatic.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for spotting that. But yes, this does indeed copy letter by letter.

Comment: @WeatherVane I honestly don't think it matters, but I updated it anyway.

Comment: It *does* matter. Not to functionality, but to efficiency for the machine - the compiler might optimise it but don't rely on the compiler doing the work for you - and for the human. My brain is not optimised to add 1 before a comparison when reading code, it just makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you use these two lines:

```
Strings[i] = malloc(strlen(temp)+1);    /* you should check return of malloc() */
Strings[i] = temp;
```

Which is incorrect. The second line just overwrites the pointer given back from `malloc()`. You need to instead use [`strcpy()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) from `<string.h>`:

```
Strings[i] = malloc(strlen(temp)+1);    
strcpy(Strings[i], temp);
```

> `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)` copies the string pointed to, from `src` to `dest`. `dest` is the destination, and `src` is the string to be copied. Returns a pointer to `dest`.

You are also not checking the return of `fgets()`, which returns `NULL` on failure. You should also consider removing the `\n` character appended by `fgets()`, as the strings you copy into `Strings[i]` will have a trailing newline, which might not be what you want.

Since another answer showed how to do it manually, you might want to also consider just using [`strdup()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to do the copying for you.

> `strdup()` returns a pointer to a new string which is duplicate of string *str*. Memory is obtained from `malloc()`, and deallocated from the heap with [`free()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm).

Here is some example code which does extra error checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 3
#define BUFFSIZE 20

int main(void) {
    char *strings[LEN] = {NULL};
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE] = {'\0'};
    size_t slen, strcnt = 0, i;

    printf("Input:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        if (fgets(buffer, BUFFSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error from fgets()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        slen = strlen(buffer);
        if (slen > 0 && buffer[slen-1] == '\n') {
            buffer[slen-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Too many characters entered\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (*buffer) {
            strings[strcnt] = strdup(buffer);
            if (strings[strcnt] == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate buffer\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            strcnt++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nOutput:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < strcnt; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
        free(strings[i]);
        strings[i] = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```